# Magento site loading stage cart item count shows '0' at few seconds

Tags: magento2, cart, count

In my cart having 5 products / item , but when i'm loading/refresh my project again cart item count shows '0' at few seconds after show only the exact count. how to solve this issue!

Comment: As answer suggests this is default behaviour. Only faster hosting will minimise time it is shown to the point you don't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Minicart is dynamic and loaded via KnockoutJS ,I believe, which means the count will be updated once the DOM is loaded and JS is executed

Comment: Thank you for your answer,i know counter  dynamic and loaded via KnockoutJS that's fine sir, but i need to prevent displaying '0' or the cart icon. before load the values.

Comment: there is any way to identify if KnockoutJS data is loaded ?

Comment: Not sure if there is an event that KnockoutJS sends upon finish, but you might try to hid the counter until the whole page is done loading